# Filter results by Current Date - 2 Days in Hadoop PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Im having some trouble finding results and converting my date and times correctly.  I have a file with date column that I've already converted the unix time to yyyy mm dd and I want to only return results that are greater than todays date - 2 days (so two days ago or greater). In SQL it would just be current_date - 2 but in PIG i am having issues replicating this.  Here is what I have:

Conversion of unixtime to readable time:

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE ID as id, epochToFormat(TIME_COLUMN, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'America/Chicago') as time;
b = FILTER b BY id == 123;
b = FILTER b by ToDate(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ==  CurrentTime(-2);
```

dump b;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use [SubtractDuration](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/SubtractDuration.html) to get 2 days before the CurrentTime().You will have to specify the duration in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
C = FILTER B BY ToDate(ToString(time,'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') > ToDate(ToString(SubtractDuration(CurrentTime(),'P2D'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: hi @inquisitive_mind, thanks for the help!  I tried your code and am getting this error below:

Comment: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: 
<line 6, column 22> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Comment: cast the time as chararray on both sides

Comment: thanks so much!  I just tried the modified script you provided and am now getting this error:  2016-12-08 22:12:16,180 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1052: 
<line 16, column 70> Cannot cast datetime to chararray

Comment: sorry I am getting same error as previously:  2016-12-08 22:51:38,503 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: 
<line 6, column 29> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToString as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Comment: ive tried this one below, which works but returns 0 results even though there should be results.  a = FILTER b by DaysBetween(CurrentTime(), ToDate(time)) < 2

Comment: Post sample data and expected results.

Comment: Sor for example, in my file i have an ID column, and a event time column which is stored like this: "ID" : 1570, "EVENT_TIME" : {
    "long" : 1350517897.  I want this ID to return if the event time is between current time and event time.

Comment: actually looks like i got it to work. i was able to use this syntax: a = FILTER b by DaysBetween(CurrentTime(), ToDate(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) < 2